# Environment variable doesn't work in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, vercel

In my Vercel's app dashboard I set environment variable `BACKEND_URL` for **Preview** environment and **dev** branch:

[image]

However after deploying it, the variable doesn't seem to work. My site can't access the api.

I added this quick way of checking what is inside `process.env.BACKEND_URL` and as expected - it is empty.

```
<Text>Backend URL: {process.env.BACKEND_URL}</Text>
```

[image]

Here is the screenshot of Vercel build which shows that the newest deploy is in fact **Preview** and from **dev** branch:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my deployed react app. When I try to call my backend using a vercel env, instead of just calling the url it appends the vercel app url to the env for no reason causing it to fail.

For example:
REACT_APP_API_UR = "https://www.example.com"
and I create a post request to my api the url it post to is:
https://yourapp.vercel.app/%22https:/www.example.com%22

Answer (score 0):

If also someone got the same problem specified by [**steward**]:

**React App** in vercel front-end app live were redirectings my api_url(backend) using rather an extension of the front end url:

- e.g : "https://restaurant-joe-front-end.vercel.app/meals"
  than using the actual extension set in my `environments variable`
  which is specially :
- e.g :"https://restaurant-joe-back-end.vercel.app/meals" (//HERE THE GOOD ONE)

I **manage to fix that error** this way :

1- **-->** **changing** in `Environment Variables` located in **settings** panel of your project :

- The name of my api_env . I was using **VITE_API_URL** instead of  using **VITE_API_BASE_URL** new name i gave to this api in local project;

2- **-->** **updating** the `api_env` in vercel settings sometimes doesn't redeploy your **project**. And it was the case for me. Still having this Error

3- **-->** **finally** **redeploying this project** on top of settings env_var like on necessary changes, **i solved the issue**

Answer (score -1):

Just recheck. I was putting http://example.com, and Vercel was not picking up my environment variable. Make sure your api url has ssl and you are calling
https://example.com in your environment variables.

Also redeploy your app on vercel by going to the deployments tab.